# Can't submit form within jquery

Tags: jquery, submit

I have a web form that will have a series of "a" tags, one for each letter of the alphabet
With `jquery` ``click(function(event){}`I retrieve the data associated with the selected a tag`var selalpha = $(this).data('page');`

This value is to be used as a parameter for a bound gridview control so I need to submit the form in this javascript code as well

I was struggling with getting the pass parameter functionality to work but finally saw my issue was that the js code that submitted the form was never firing.

This is my original code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
       $("a").click(function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
        var selalpha = $(this).data('page');
          document.getElementById("alpha").value = selalpha; 

            x = document.getElementsByName("myform");
            x.submit[0];

        });

      });`
```

This returned error “form.submit is not a function”

Searching for this error suggested it comes from having another element named or with the ID or name    “submit” somewhere inside the form however this is not the case.

Also all the suggested solutions had the submit itself inside a function so I thought that what was needed and created a function and moved the code inside the function

However I have not be able to invoke the function without a syntax error and I have tried placing the invocation in every possible location I can think of

Here is the current version of the code which returns the error “Unexpected token : at `function dosub();`

**PLEASE NOTE:** Revised working version based on my last comment

```
<script type="text/javascript">    $(document).ready(function () {     
     $("a").click(function (event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         var selalpha = $(this).data('page');
         document.getElementById("alpha").value = selalpha;
      $( "#form2" ).submit();    
          });

        });
```

Comment: SOrry, I'm struggling with the code formatting,I'll keep trying

Comment: This `x(0).submit();` should be this `x[0].submit();` use brackets to index an array in javascript, not parenthesis.

Comment: Select each code block, press the { } button,

Comment: I had the correct brackets following the submit in the code, but somehow when I was preparing the post in word,I must have changed them./The code did not work with the correct formatting of   x[0].submit(); at any time

Comment: Right now you are calling dosub() while the functionname is dosubm()

Comment: Oops - you don’t write the word ’function’ if you call a function. Just: ’dosubm();’ in your case to call it

Comment: jesus sorry for the sloppy post, I revised the code ( see above) but while the function is being called, I am still getting the error form submit is not a function

Comment: I found the solution by using jquery to submit the form instead of plain javascript     $( "#form2" ).submit();  I found this solution in jquery  api documentation

Comment: thank you all for your help